# Net::OpenTimeout (execution expired) exception on Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, deployment, telnet, sidekiq

I'm using sidekiq to to queue the emails my Rails application will send. Sending emails works in development, but in production sidekiq will get a network timeout error. What's going on?

Here's my config in `production.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 578,
  domain:               ENV["PPRODUCTION_DOMAIN"],
  user_name:            ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
  password:             ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"],
  authentication:       :plain,
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}

config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
```

I have tried the following:

1. Disabling IPv6 and setting IPv4 as the preferred
2. Using a non-standard port (2525) instead of 587
3. Tried connecting via `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`. I get the following error: `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable`. It might be worth noting that I'm operating behind a proxy - should there be an additional setup in this case?
4. `sudo ufw allow 587`

I'm on an Ubuntu 14.04 server and have set up my app using unicorn and nginx.

I've been at this for days. :( Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:**

I also tried the following:

5. Remove sidekiq to send the email using Rails' mailer instead. Same results.
6. Connect via `telnet smtp.gmail.com 465`. This one works so I tried setting the port in production to 465, but I still get the same error.
7. Remove the domain, using our production domain, and using `localhost:3000`. Nothing happens.

Comment: 1) Try to remove `domain` option but I don't think that it help. 2) Some providers/hosters block all SMTP traffic. Seems like this is your case because you checked this use telnet command. Try to contact your hosting support.

Comment: Did you try `telnet  74.125.206.108 587` ? Maybe IPv6 is not realy disabled.A proxy can indicate a problem. Maybe a firewall within your network prohibits smtp access to external servers.

Comment: @slowjack2k I get the following errors: `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out`.

`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6` also gives me an output of `1` so I'm sue that IPv6 is disabled.

Comment: @slowjack2k I was able to make `telnet smtp.gmail.com 465` work. So I changed the port in `config/environments/production.rb` and restarted the Rails app. I also removed siekiq and just used ActionMailer. But I still get `Net::OpenTimeout (execution expired)`

Comment: Maybe it has to do with https://google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps seetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow fixed it by changing the port to `456` instead.

I changed the port because for some reason, `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` doesn't work but `telnet smtp.gmail.com 465` does. `587` may have been blocked by the network.

Also, I'm not sure if the following changes also helped, but I also changed the authentication to `:login` instead of `:plain` and added `ssl: true`. Hope this helps out anyone who encounters the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Rails guide's](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) Action mailer basics, the port number you are giving is incorrect. As it is 587 not 578.

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'example.com',
  user_name:            '<username>',
  password:             '<password>',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

I hope this helps !!